# Deleting dirs after finishing a command prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

I have a python script that ends with running a program (iexpress.exe) in a dos prompt.
The program that runs in dos prompt, uses a dir called workdir.
After the program has finished in the dos prompt I would like python to delete the dir. 
I have just made a simple solution of putting a delay of 30sec:

```
time.sleep(30)
removeall(workdir)
os.rmdir(workdir)
```

But how should I do it, if python should delete the dir right after the process has finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the python program call the exe and not fall off the end

ie call the exe using [subprocess.Popen](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/subprocess.html)

The when the exe finishes you are still in python